# Get sol out from NFT token account

Tags: spl-token, nft, spl-token-program

I have an NFT seen here https://solscan.io/token/8MDodzxDuenjCWkH9twDfjawQzzjKAHERK7RSsX6LEDd where SOL was sent to the actual token account rather than to my wallet, the owner of the NFT. I'm looking for a way to withdraw the SOL from here. I do not think its possible though since the token program is the owner of the account.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the NFT to a different Token Account and Close this Token Account all SOL would be transferred to the destination wallet you provided.
Check this out for more info [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L199)